# Why can't I use my discrete lowpass filter?

Tags: signal-processing

I am trying demonstrate a discrete IIR lowpass filter using the feature of [RecurrenceFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceFilter.html?q=RecurrenceFilter) described here.
[image: documentation]
This is my filter.

```
Clear[s,z];
tf=ButterworthFilterModel[{"Lowpass",{1.45,3.92},{3,20}},s];
dtf=Chop@ToDiscreteTimeModel[tf,1,z];
BodePlot[dtf,{0,Pi},PlotLayout->"Magnitude",
    ScalingFunctions->{"Linear","Absolute"},PlotRange->All
]
```

[image: Bode Plot]
This is my filter input.

```
signal=Table[{t,Cos[0.07 t]+Cos[2.8 t]},{t,0,80}];
ListLinePlot[signal,Epilog->{Point@signal}]
```

[image: plot of signal]
How can I demonstrate that this filter will attenuate a (high frequency) and let a (low frequency) go through? My attempt below doesn't work.

```
filtered=RecurrenceFilter[dtf,signal];
ListPlot[filtered]
```

[image: filtered output]

Comment: It's interpreting your list of pairs as a 2D array rather than a time series I think. Either wrap signal in `TimeSeries` or define `signal=Table[Cos[0.07 t]+Cos[2.8 t],{t,0,80}]` and everything looks fine.

Comment: @N.J. Evans, Yes that solves it.

Comment: N.J. Evans has solved the main problem.  You don't seem to have considered frequency pre-warping. Are you aware of this? Perhaps not a problem in your case.